# Is this correct for rock-paper-scissor game | Python?

Tags: python, input, reset

The question is :
*Make a two-player Rock-Paper-Scissors game. (Hint: Ask for player plays (using input), compare them, print out a message of congratulations to the winner, and ask if the players want to start a new game)*

```
player1 = input("Player 1: ")
player2 = input("Player 2: ")

if player1 == "rock" and player2 == "paper":
    print("Player 2 is the winner!!")
elif player1 == "rock" and player2 == "scissor":
    print("Player 1 is the winner!!")
elif player1 == "paper" and player2 == "scissor":
    print("Player 2 is the winner!!")
elif player1 == player2:
    print("It's a tie!!")
```

After asking  if the players want to start a new game, how to restart the code?

Comment: This seems like an assignment. Please solve it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop, i.e. something like

```
play = 'Y'

while play=='Y':
    # your original code

    play = input("Do you want to play again (Y/N): ")
```

Also I'd suggest you check that the responses from the user are valid (i.e. what if they type `potatoe`, in your code nothing will print if one or both players don't respond with rock, scissors or paper. You should also look at the lower() command and convert the answer to lower case for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
    options = {"rock" : 0, "paper": 1, "scissors": 2} #correct inputs
    ratio = options[player1] - options[player2]

    if player1 not in options.keys() and player2 not in options.keys():
        return 0 #tie, both inputs wrong

    if player1 not in options.keys():
        return 2 #Player1 input wrong, Player 2 wins

    if player2 not in options.keys():
        return 1 #Player2 input wrong, Player 1 wins
    
    if ratio == 0:
        return 0 #tie
    if ratio == 1 or ratio == -2:
        return 1 #Player 1 wins
    return 2 #Player 2 wins
```